# Java Runtime Fatal Error when debugging app

Tags: java

So I have been trying to run my Java application in IntelliJ for a while now. Every time I do, I receive

[image: this message]

I thought maybe it was my app at first but I've tried a few Java apps that I found on Github and I receive the same error. I have updated both my Java and JDK to the latest versions but to no avail.

I'm still somewhat new to Java, so looking at this log file has confused me. The log file can be found here: https://cdn.mrboolean.com/hs_err_pid22108.log

Comment: You say you've updated your JDK/JRE, but are you *running* those updated versions ? Does the version number in your error message reflect the JVM version you would expect ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes, sorry I should've mentioned that. I've changed all of that in the Project Settings. My project settings can be seen here: https://cdn.mrboolean.com/xpM20xAgbLXRoH1.jpg